# Facebook share count stays zero

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-fql, facebook-sharer

I'm having a problem now with Facebook share button. The url i use for sharer is:

```
var facebook = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D="+encodeURIComponent(title)+'&p%5Bsummary%5D='+encodeURIComponent(desc)+'&p%5Burl%5D='+encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Now, the problem is with strange behaviour of the count.. whenever i share a url from the website, it gets shared ok, and i can see that the url is the same as i want, i.e.

```
mydomain.com/post/123/vote/5/
```

But, when i request share_count from link_stat table with FQL, it shows 0

Later then, if i go to my wall and click Share below that shared story and share it again, the count rises by 1

PS: the og:meta tags are set up on that page, and Facebook URL linter shows them ok

did anyone have same bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharer was deprecated around March 2011 - Involver has a good post on it:
http://blog.involver.com/2011/03/15/whats-happening-to-facebook-share/

Currently the best way to share is using the Like + Send button or the Feed Dialog:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/